# Pug won't display pictures

Tags: css, image, express, pug, vs-web-site-project

I just want to play around in express but I have trouble understanding the view engine. I don't get the background picture, or any picture for that matter to show up. I have tried the same css code in html where it seemed fine but in pug it's just blank.

I have the following structure:

```
-public
--home.jpg
--styles.css
-views
--index.pug 
-main.js
```

Apart from this the view engine seems to work fine to render the pug page and simple css logic is loaded to the page.

```
main.js 

const debug = require("debug");
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const timeout = require("connect-timeout");
dotenv.config();

//Load View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Home Route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Background-image should load the image

```
index.pug

doctype html
html
  head
    style 
      include ../public/styles.css
    title Basic Website
  body
    .container 
      .background-image
        .header
          h1. 
            The basic website
```

The container's and image's properties shows up when I inspect the page, but the image is still not visable

```
styles.css

.container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/*Background image*/
/*****************/
.background-image{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("home.jpg");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Express JS does not allow to serve static files likes images, videos etc. Static files are downloaded by clients from server. However, if
> we have to serve static files, we will have to enable middleware
> dedicated for this purpose. To do this, first of all we will create a
> folder or directory named public in our project directory then add the
> following line of code in our index.js.

```
//use middleware to serve static files
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

After that it is possible to just add pictures to the public folder and refer to them in pug with:

img(src="/name.png", alt="picture")

Taken from: https://learncybers.com/static-files-in-express-js/